# how to deal with ZIP archives in DIRED?

Tags: dired

I want to work easier with archives in Emacs dired-mode. And I think that my needs are not only mine.

What I want? Two things in Dired:

1. `z` to zip file or dir on cursor (or all marked files/dirs if marks are exists); the name of new archive should be changeable (but if one file/dir selected than name should be the same);
2. `Z` to unarchive any type of archives (zip or gz or tar) at cursor; by default content should be placed in new directory with the same name.

How can one achieve that?

Comment: @Drew, `Z` in Dired replace (not added another) file with it's `*.gz` archive (not `*.zip`).

Comment: Yes. Apparently (now) that is not what you want. But you have not specified what you want. As I said, the question is not very clear. I suppose that for someone who is familiar with `dired-atool`, or who takes the time to follow the link and study what it does, the question will be clearer, but you should clarify the question itself, IMHO.

Comment: @Drew, I rewrite my question. Is it clearly now?

Comment: This feature is coming up in the next emacs release (25.1) [[Relevant commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-25&id=f6ece2420c3dc6f3dde06c7f8722f5b0b7e1ef4a)]. If you wish, you can try the 3rd pretest (25.0.92) from [here](ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest). *Copying **@abo-abo**.*

Comment: @Drew, sorry, it's my fault! Surely I mean "inside of Dired".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### emacs 25.x

The emacs 25.1 release will have in-built support for handling different kinds of archives from within dired. Below is the relevant excerpt from the `NEWS` file (`C-h C-n`).

```
+++
*** The command `dired-do-compress' bound to `Z' now can compress
directories and decompress zip files.

+++
*** New command `dired-do-compress-to' bound to `c' can be used to
compress many marked files into a single named archive.  The
compression command is determined from the new
`dired-compress-files-alist' variable.
```

---

#### `dired-do-compress` | `Z`

Check out the `dired-compress-file-suffixes` variable to get a list of supported compressed file formats. The correct program will be used to uncompress a file (or files) when using the `Z` binding (`dired-do-compress`).

*While the above will uncompress a wide range of formats, it will always compress using `gzip`.*

#### `dired-do-compress-to` | `c`

Check out the `dired-compress-files-alist` variable to get a list of supported file formats that can be compressed **to** using the `c` binding (`dired-do-compress-to`).

As of emacs 25.1, it supports compressing using `tar` + (`gzip`/`bzip2`/`xz`) or `zip`.

Comment: How to get Emacs 25.1? Or the 25.0.92 version is latest for now?

Comment: @drobnbobn Emacs 25.1 isn't out yet, 25.0.92 is the latest beta.